# why this javascripts elements not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new at programming and i started with html and css. Now i'm using bootstrap and i can't use some javascript elements in my page (like tooltips or popovers).  i have in the head tag bootstrap.min.css and at the end of the body tag bootstrap.bundle.min.js script tag (it's empty). I don't know if that is enough to make that work. As you can see i'm new at this, and i don't know anything of javascript, so i can't initialize a function on my own if that is necessary. The popover is not appearing when clicking the button, and tooltips shows but with like 1sec delay and not styled.

i have in my html from bootstrap:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

in the head tag

at the bottom of the body tag i have:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this button is not working when clicking

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

and i have this atributtes for the tooltip

```
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

Comment: pls show us the code for debugger

Comment: RTM Getting Started: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/